# Compare two arrays and create a new array with the differences, accounting for duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Lets say I have two arrays containing numbers..

[1,1,7,6],
[1,7]

I need to create a new array out of the numbers that do not appear in the second array, but also account for there being two 1s.

I have tried using lodash's `_.difference([1,1,7,6],[1,7])`

as well as some other plain Javascript functions, but they do not account for the there being two 1s, so I just end up with `[6]`

My desired outcome would be `[1,6]`

Order does not matter

Comment: show example desired output array

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could simply iterate over the second array and splice the first occurrence in the first Array for each entry...

Comment: Do you expect `[1, 6]`?

Comment: So, does the order of the array's matter too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the first array. For each element in the first array, search the second. If it exists, insert `null` into that index. If it doesn't exist, then push it to a new array with your differences

```js
const difference = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const differenceArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        const matchingIdx = arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]);
        if (matchingIdx !== -1) {
            arr2[matchingIdx] = null
        } else {
            differenceArr.push(arr1[i])
        }
    }
    return differenceArr
}

console.log(difference([1, 1, 7, 7, 6],[1, 1, 7]))
```

Comment: @Grambam No problem. One thing to note is that this is a slow algorithm (straight up n^2). Don't use this on very large arrays. By large I mean arrays with thousands of entries or you're using this algorithm repeatedly and quickly. Regarding downvotes: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ . Specifically paragraph 4, which details literally everything that just happened. Happy coding, my friend ;).

Answer (score 2):

A shorter script:

```
function differenceWithDuplicates(a, b) {
    while(b.length) a.splice(a.indexOf(b[0]), +a.includes(b.shift()));
    return a;
}
console.log(differenceWithDuplicates([1, 1, 7, 6],[1, 7]));
```

Or just make the while, without call it inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
const diff = (array1, array2) => {

    const _array2 = Array.from(array2);
    const difference = [];

    array1.forEach((array1Item) => {
        const matchedIndex = _array2.findIndex(array2Item => array2Item === array1Item);
        if (matchedIndex > -1) {
            // Remove from second array
            _array2.splice(matchedIndex, 1);
        } else {
            // No match found, add to difference array
            difference.push(array1Item);
        }
    });

    // Return the remaining items in _array2 and difference
    return [ ..._array2, ...difference ];
}
```

By copying the second array, you can remove any matches from it. And by combining that with matching array1 > array2, you get differences in both directions, including duplicates.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3v34tjnq/